# How to receive mpegts multicast steam on vlc

Tags: vlc, mpeg2-ts

I have developed a mpegs-ts streaming server which sends multicast stream to multicast ip address 224.2.3.51:3200. I am running my streaming server in a linux server. How can I receive and play this multicast stream on vlc running in local windows machine?

Answer (score 2):

To receive a mpeg2-ts stream in vlc

- In vlc, in network stream settings, we have to give input as udp://@ipaddress:portnumber. In this case udp://@224.2.3.51:3200
- We need to make sure that both the streaming server and vlc media player are part of same subnetwork.